# Program no longer continues after cin.ignore

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to check if the user input is corresponding to the data type or not.

I've written the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
 
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::array;
 
void inv()
{
    cout << "invalid input, try again: ";
}
 
int main()
{
    constexpr array test { "Yes", "no", "test", "maybe", "eventually", "could be", };
 
    int n;
 
    do
    {
        cin >> n;
 
        if (cin.fail() || n < 0|| n >= test.size())
            {   
                inv();
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()); // I have the feeling the issue is somewhere here
            }        
    }
 
    while (false);
 
    cout << test[n];
    return 0;
}
```

This is just for testing. The issue is now that while a correct input works just as intended, an incorrect input goes to the `if` statement, and then after the `cin.ignore` part, nothing happens.

I tried to add a `break` and a `return` statement inside the `if` statement, and in an `else` statement, which didn't help.

I also checked where exactly the code was breaking, by testing it via a small text output in different places.

My goal is for the program to exit the `if` statement after the check, so that it can then return to the start of the `do`, awaiting another attempt by the user.

Here are the two scenarios regarding input/output.

If the input is correct the program continues and outputs one of the strings from the array, for example if the input is 0, then the output is "Yes".

If the input is incorrect the program puts out "Invalid input, try again: ", followed by the user being able to input something, but the program doesn't do anything at all. If I add cout << "test"; before the cin.ignore it gets executed, but if I put it after the cin.ignore it doesn't get executed.

Comment: really nothing? The code should print `Yes` when input fails. It does so here https://godbolt.org/z/d71z3jf56.

Comment: `while(false)` this loop cannot have more than 1 iteration

Comment: Do not rely on littering your code with text output for debugging - learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) / [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please edit the quesiton to clarify what exactly is the input and what exactly is the output

Comment: I've updated the question to include the input and output. Hopefully this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Why `do-while` to begin with if it will run once? [learn c++](https://www.learncpp.com).

Comment: Recursively call `inv()` `if cin.fail() •••`? Why not call `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore(•••)` first.

Comment: inv() was added prior to cin.clear etc because otherwise it wouldn't show up. In the updated code in my answer the placement doesn't matter that much it seems, as long as it's in the if statement.

Comment: As author posted in answer this is a typo (wrong order of arguments). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Changing
`cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max())`

to

`cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`

fixed the issue I was having.

I also updated the code to make it loop infinite until the user input is correct. Some have pointed out it only loops once, but that's fixed now.

Here's the updated code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
 
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::array;
 
void inv()
{
    cout << "invalid input, try again: ";
}
 
int main()
{
 
    constexpr array test { "Yes", "no", "test", "maybe", "eventually", "could be", };
 
    int n;
 
    while(true)
    {
        cin >> n;
 
        if (cin.fail() || n < 0|| n >= test.size())
            {   
                inv();
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }    
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
 
    cout << test[n];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Share your new code let’s know how better it got.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the new code

Comment: You should not call `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` if an `int` was read successfully. I/O and Value Validation are two separate steps. Call `clear()` and `ignore()` only if `cin` failed to read the `int` at all, eg: `do{ if (cin >> n) { if (n >= 0 && n < test.size()) break; } else { cin.clear(); cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); } inv(); } while (true);`